# Is it undefined behaviour to allocate overlarge stack structures?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

This is a C specification question.

We all know this is legal C and should work fine on any platform:

```
/* Stupid way to count the length of a number */
int count_len(int val) {
    char buf[256];
    return sprintf(buf, "%d", val);
}
```

But this is almost guaranteed to crash:

```
/* Stupid way to count the length of a number */
int count_len(int val) {
    char buf[256000000];
    return sprintf(buf, "%d", val);
}
```

The difference is that the latter program blows the stack and will probably crash. But, purely semantically, it really isn't any different than the previous program.

According to the C spec, is the latter program actually undefined behavior? If so, what distinguishes it from the former? If not, what in the C spec says it's OK for a conforming implementation to crash?

(If this differs between C89/C99/C11/C++*, this would be interesting too).

Comment: I think this question is equally valid in C++.

Comment: @Mysticial: Good point, I added the C++ tag in case anyone knows the situation there.

Comment: @Mysticial but the answer might be different between C and C++, particularly since you're talking about fine print of the standards.

Comment: No, it isn't undefined.  If the machine doesn't have enough ram, it will -- well, not crash exactly, but fail to load into RAM to start with -- i.e. in this case the loader for the OS will not ever get the program fully in memory to run.  Nothing the spec has to say can change that.

Comment: @JohnH There's a slight difference here. When you're allocating heap memory (`malloc()`, `new`), the standard clearly defines what will happen if the allocation fails. (return `NULL`, `throw badalloc`) For the stack, it's less clear - hence this question.

Comment: @JohnH: Let's say the machine uses a stack, and allocating an array of whatever size moves the stack pointer by that much. If the amount isn't sensible, the program probably will crash through some sort of hardware exception, like dividing by zero. It's not the same as allocating memory via malloc (it's also not the same in the sense Mystical mentioned).

Comment: @JohnH: That's what is expected to happen for static storage class, but this question appears to be about automatic storage class.

Comment: The memory size available for the stack in an implementation issue.  The C and C++ standards to not specify the minimal or maximum size for a stack; the standards don't require an implementation to have a stack.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: Using that logic, (signed) integer overflow isn't undefined behaviour either, because the integer limits are implementation-specific. However, integer overflow *is* undefined.

Comment: @someguy: *In practice* signed integer overflow *is* implementation defined.

Comment: @Zan Lynx: That makes no sense. Just because in a particular implementation it may correspond to the signed integer wrapping for example doesn't mean it's "implementation defined". The behaviour is still undefined.

Comment: @someguy: It's implementation-defined if a particular implementation documents and provides a guarantee a certain behavior.  I quote "Permissible undefined behavior
ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to **behaving during translation or
program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment** (with or without the issuance of
a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message)."  Relying on behavior documented by the implementation is perfectly safe, although non-portable.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I don't agree with that because, if you look at the definition for undefined behaviour, it says "possible undefined behavior ranges from ... to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message) ..." Remember we are talking about the C standard. In that respect, it's still undefined. Going back to my original point, that's what matters. Edit: Haha, while I was typing you add in the same quote :p.

Comment: @someguy: It's undefined by the C++ (and C) Standard, and defined by some (many) implementations which document a guarantee.  If you know you are only ever using one of those implementations, you can treat it as defined behavior.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: That I agree with, and I wouldn't bash you if you did rely on that behaviour if you were targetting specific implementations. But I think we've derailed a bit since it is about the standard in the end :p.

Comment: @someguy: Now that we've got a baseline, I think Zan is completely wrong to say it (signed overflow) is implementation-defined in practice.  Even though the underlying hardware instructions for signed arithmetic have well-defined semantics, the C++ (or C) implementations do not translate that to a guaranteed behavior, and optimize on the assumption that signed overflow does not occur.  For example, `signed x = f(); if (x + 5 < x) { ... }` is *dead code*, on every implementation I've seen, even though the compare instruction (or equivalent) properly sets the `Z` and `N` bits (or equivalent).

Comment: For C11 ISO/IEC indicates certain things are outside the scope of the standard, among them "the size or complexity of a program and its data that will exceed the capacity of any
speciﬁc data-processing system or the capacity of a particular processor;" and  "all minimal requirements of a data-processing system that is capable of supporting a conforming implementation."
http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=57853

Comment: Minor note: A sufficient sized buffer for `"%d"` can be had with `char buf[sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 2];`

Comment: @chux: Thanks. Note that there are a number of superior implementations of this code which use negligible extra space, such as repeated division (with sign correction), using the return value of `snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", val)`, or (as you note) using a properly-sized buffer. This example was simply the first thing that popped into my head.

Comment: @JohnH: Why would the program fail to load? The memory for `buf` isn't allocated until the `count_len` function is called. And if the behavior isn't undefined, then what defines the behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Language standards for C([89](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt),[99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf),[11](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=57853)) begin with a scope section with this wording (also found in some C++, C#, Fortran and Pascal standards):

This International Standard does not specify

- the size or complexity of a program and its data that will exceed the capacity of any speciﬁc data-processing system or the capacity of a particular processor;
- all minimal requirements of a data-processing system that is capable of supporting a conforming implementation.

The gcc compiler does offer [an option to check for stack overflow at runtime](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Stack-Overflow-Checking.html)

**21.1 Stack Overflow Checking**

> For most operating systems, gcc does not perform stack overflow checking by default. This means that if the main environment task or some other task exceeds the available stack space, then unpredictable behavior will occur. Most native systems offer some level of protection by adding a guard page at the end of each task stack. This mechanism is usually not enough for dealing properly with stack overflow situations because a large local variable could “jump” above the guard page. Furthermore, when the guard page is hit, there may not be any space left on the stack for executing the exception propagation code. Enabling stack checking avoids such situations.
>   To activate stack checking, compile all units with the gcc option -fstack-check. For example:

```
gcc -c -fstack-check package1.adb
```

> Units compiled with this option will generate extra instructions to check that any use of the stack (for procedure calls or for declaring local variables in declare blocks) does not exceed the available stack space. If the space is exceeded, then a Storage_Error exception is raised.

There was an attempt during the standardization process for C99 to [make a stronger statement within the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n853.htm) that while size and complexity are beyond the scope of the standard the implementer has a responsibility to document the limits.

The rationale was

> The definition of conformance has always been a problem with the C
>   Standard, being described by one author as "not even rubber teeth, more
>   like rubber gums". Though there are improvements in C9X compared with C89,
>   many of the issues still remain.
>
> This paper proposes changes which, while not perfect, hopefully improve the
>   situation.

The following wording was suggested for inclusion to section 5.2.4.1

- translation or execution might fail if the size or complexity of a program or its data exceeds the capacity of the implementation.
- The implementation shall document a way to determine if the size or complexity of a correct program exceeds or might exceed the capacity of the implementation.

> 5.2.4.1. An implementation is always free to state that a given program is
>   too large or too complex to be translated or executed. However, to stop
>   this being a way to claim conformance while providing no useful facilities
>   whatsoever, the implementer must show provide a way to determine whether a
>   program is likely to exceed the limits. The method need not be perfect, so
>   long as it errs on the side of caution.
>   One way to do this would be to have a formula which converted values such
>   as the number of variables into, say, the amount of memory the compiler
>   would need. Similarly, if there is a limit on stack space, the formula need
>   only show how to determine the stack requirements for each function call
>   (assuming this is the only place the stack is allocated) and need not work
>   through every possible execution path (which would be impossible in the
>   face of recursion). The compiler could even have a mode which output a
>   value for each function in the program.
>   
>   The proposed wording did not make it into the C99 standard, and therefore this area remained outside the scope of the standard.  Section 5.2.4.1 of C99 does list these limits
>
> The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one program that contains at least one instance of every one of the following limits:

- 127 nesting levels of blocks
- 63 nesting levels of conditional inclusion
- 12 pointer, array, and function declarators (in any combinations) modifying an arithmetic, structure, union, or incomplete type in a declaration
- 63 nesting levels of parenthesized declarators within a full declarator
- 63 nesting levels of parenthesized expressions within a full expression
- 63 significant initial characters in an internal identifier or a macro name (each universal character name or extended source character is considered a single character)
- 31 significant initial characters in an external identifier (each universal character name specifying a short identifier of 0000FFFF or less is considered 6 characters, each universal character name specifying a short identifier of 00010000 or more is considered 10 characters, and each extended source character is considered the same number of characters as the corresponding universal character name, if any)
- 4095 external identifiers in one translation unit
- 511 identifiers with block scope declared in one block
- 4095 macro identifiers simultaneously defined in one preprocessing translation unit
- 127 parameters in one function definition
- 127 arguments in one function call
- 127 parameters in one macro definition
- 127 arguments in one macro invocation
- 4095 characters in a logical source line
- 4095 characters in a character string literal or wide string literal (after concatenation)
- 65535 bytes in an object (in a hosted environment only)
- 15 nesting levels for #included files
- 1023 case labels for a switch statement (excluding those for any nested switch statements)
- 1023 members in a single structure or union
- 1023 enumeration constants in a single enumeration
- 63 levels of nested structure or union definitions in a single struct-declaration-list

Comment: Yes, I checked these implementation-defined limits closely, and there's none regarding function recursion, only template recursion (in the C++ version).

Comment: @BenVoigt Do you think it was an oversight or intentional? I get the impression the committee didn't want to go down the slippery slope of defining minimum limits in an area that is very much under the control of the runtime environment and the operating system, such as storage for automatic variables.

Comment: @amdn: Fair question. The standard clearly implies that there must be enough stack space to make one function call, but I'm not sure it would require more than two bytes of stack [if an implementation had insufficient stack to accommodate nested function calls, recursion would be impossible in practice, and thus it could store all method parameters statically].  A fundamental problem I think is that requiring that implementations provide more than 64K of stack would pose problems for many smaller implementations, but saying that any demand for more than 64K of stack was UB would...

Answer (score 3):

In C++, Annex B indicates that the maximum size of an object is an implementation-specific finite number.  That would tend to limit arrays with automatic storage class.

However, I'm not seeing something specifically for space accumulated by all automatic variables on the call stack, which is where a stack overflow ought to be triggered.  I'm also not seeing a recursion limit in Annex B, although that would be closely related.

Comment: Does it state what the outcome will be if you exceed the maximum?

Comment: @Mark: No, the behavior of exceeding implementation-specific limits is not defined.

Comment: Well, that does not make allocating a number of valid sized object in a recursion undefined behavior, i. e. `void foo() { int[1024]; foo(); }` does not violate this restriction, yet it will crash quite quickly.

Comment: @cmaster: Right, that's why my second paragraph.

Comment: @cmaster: Is there anything in the standard which would forbid a compiler from doing whatever it likes given any program which performs subroutine calls from any method other than `main`?

Comment: @supercat: The standards definitely define semantics for making function calls.  Subroutines don't exist in the vocabulary of C and C++.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Whether you call it a subroutine or function, my point was that `main` has to be able to call one function with up to 127 parameters, but there's no requirement that such a function (or, for that matter, any function other than `main` with any number of parameters) needs to be able to call anything.

Comment: @supercat: What are you seeing that gives the function-call operator different behavior in `main` from other functions?

Comment: @BenVoigt: The fact that a program must allow a function call with 127 arguments implies that the stack must be large enough to accommodate a call depth of one.  Is there anything in the standard that would promise a stack large enough to handle a call depth of two?

Comment: @supercat: There's nothing in the Standard that specifies how a compiler should implement function call and return.  In particular there's no requirement for a stack to exist.  If the hardware support is so bad as to not stack multiple return addresses, the compiler will need its own logic for tracking return addresses.  Of course, at some point the program may exceed the system capacity, in which case it is excused from meeting all the Standard's requirements.  But a single function call is clearly not enough to support all the examples contained in the Standard and described as valid.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Fair point about other examples within the standard. Do any of the examples call a function recursively via pointer? If not, could an implementation compile recursive functions by in-line expanding to some depth and having any overly-deep calls launch the missiles? What's the deepest level of function calls shown in any examples? More than three?

Comment: @supercat: Well, now we're in a situation where it depends greatly on which draft of which Standard.  C++ certainly loves to specify that certain library functions call other functions, that constructors call subobject constructors, etc.  I'm not sure what's the maximum depth, but certainly the iostreams stuff involves formatted `operator<<` calling unformatted `put` or `write` which calls `sputc` which calls `overflow` which calls `out` on a `codecvt` facet.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah, C++ requires some significant nesting.  What about C, though?

Answer (score 3):

The C standard is silent on all issues relating to stack overflow. This is a bit strange since it's very vocal in just about every other corner of C programming. AFAIK there is no specification that a certain amount of automatic storage must be available,  and no way of detecting or recovering from exhaustion of the space available for automatic storage. The abstract machine is assumed to have an unlimited amount of automatic storage.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the behavior is undefined by omission -- *if* a 250,000,000-byte local object actually exceeds the implementation's capacity.

Quoting the 2011 ISO C standard, section 1 (Scope), paragraph 2:

> This International Standard does not specify
>   [...]
>   - the size or complexity of a program and its data that will exceed the capacity of any
>   specific data-processing system or the capacity of a particular processor

So the standard explicitly acknowledges that a program may exceed the capacity of an implementation.

I think we can safely assume that a program that exceeds the capacity of an implementation is not required to behave the same way as one that does not; otherwise there would be no point in mentioning it.

Since nothing in the standard defines the behavior of such a program, the behavior is undefined. This is specified by section 4 (Conformance), paragraph 2:

> [...]
>  Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this
>   International Standard by the words "undefined behavior" or by the
>   omission of any explicit definition of behavior. There is no
>   difference in emphasis among these three; they all describe "behavior
>   that is undefined".

Of course an implementation on most modern computers could easily allocate 250 million bytes of memory; that's only a small fraction of the available RAM on the computer I'm typing this on, for example. But many operating systems place a fairly low limit on the amount of stack space that a program can allocate.

(Incidentally, I'm assuming that the code in the question is a fragment of some complete program that actually calls the function. As it stands, the code has no behavior, since there's no call to `count_len`, nor is there a `main` function. I might not normally mention that, but you *did* use the "language-lawyer" tag.)

Anyone who would argue that the behavior is not undefined should explain either (a) why having the program crash does not make the implementation non-conforming, or (b) how a program crash is within the scope of defined behavior (even if it's implementation-defined or unspecified).

Comment: I believe the standard does not need to specify the behavior of programs whose size or complexity exceeds the capacity of an implementation beyond saying it's outside its scope.  If the standard had intended for considerations outside its scope to be considered undefined behavior it would have said so explicitly, I don't think the "omission" clause was meant to cover what has been explicitly deemed outside the scope of the standard.

Comment: @amdn: Are you saying there's a distinction that the standard explicitly says is undefined, and behavior that the standard simply does not specify? The standard itself says otherwise. I see no real difference between behavior that the standard doesn't define because it's "outside its scope", and behavior that the standard doesn't define for some other reason.

Comment: Yes, I think so, they went through the trouble of specifying what is and isn't in scope of the standard and they wen't through the trouble of specifying, within the standard, the three classes of undefined: violation of shall/shall not, explicitly using the word undefined, and any omissions.  Out of scope supersedes everything within the standard.

Comment: @amdn: Hmm. You may be right. Still, I'd say that the behavior of a program that exceeds the implementation's capacity qualifies as "behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
for which this International Standard imposes no requirements", which is precisely the definition of "undefined behavior". Still, the debate is about the meaning of the phrase "undefined behavior"; I think we're in agreement that the standard does not define the behavior.

Comment: Yes, we agree about that, I believe they didn't define it, consciously, by voluntarily declaring out of their jurisdiction.